# Fractional Linear Transformation map with one attracting fixed point and one repulsive fixed point. Must every orbit go to the attracting point?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

Consider a fractional linear transformation 
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$. Here $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers with $ad-bc=1$.

Given a point $w$ in $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$, we say the orbit of $w$ is the set 
$$\mathrm{orb}(w)=\{f^k(w)| k\in\mathbb Z\}.$$

Assume that $f$ has a unique attracting fixed point $z_+$ and a unique repulsive fixed point $z_-$. That is, $\mathrm{orb}(z_+)=\{z_+\}$, $\mathrm{orb}(z_-)=\{z_-\}$, $|f'(z_+)|<1$,  $|f'(z_-)|>1$, and $z_+$ and $z_-$ are the only points whose orbits contain only a single element.

Is it true that for any $z\in (\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\})\setminus \{z_-\}$,  we have $z_+\in \overline{\mathrm{orb}(z)}$? If it is true, how do we prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things become easier if the fixed points are zero and infinity. I.e. instead of $f$ we consider the “conjugate” transformation
$$
 g = T \circ f \circ T^{-1}
$$
where $T(z) = \frac{z - z_+}{z - z_-}$. Show that $g$ is necessarily of the form
$$
 g(w) = \lambda w
$$
for a complex constant $\lambda$, and
$$
 |\lambda| = |g'(0)| = |f'(z_+)| < 1 \, .
$$
It follows that for all $z \ne z_-$, 
$$
f^k(z) = T^{-1}(\lambda^k T(z)) \to z_+
$$
for $k \to \infty$.